# Stripe from sandbox to live, question about source?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I have stripe connect working in testing mode but am curious about "source"..

The following code pre-authorizes payments in my controller:

```
token = params[:stripeToken]
            payment_form = params[:payment_form]

            customer = Stripe::Customer.create({
              :source  => 'tok_visa',
              :email => params[:stripeEmail],
            })

            charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
              amount: @amount,
              currency: 'usd',
              customer: customer.id,
              capture: false,
          })
```

I want to go into live mode, but I need to update the source to something other than 'tok_visa'...

What is supposed to go there?

So far, I collect the customer token and stripe token, i tried using both in that spot and neither work.

When i use

`:source => @order.order_token,`

in either the custom create or charge create, it tells me:

`Stripe::InvalidRequestError (No such token: KFU8PmscYRDsXs1234560jG4sn8J-S8TMi123456BUBkWr9aOvw):`

This is while using test number :4242424242424242

It works with the test token, but not number? Is this normal?

UPDATE:

When i use the following:

```
token = params[:stripeToken]
            payment_form = params[:payment_form]

            customer = Stripe::Customer.create({
              # :source  => 'tok_visa',
              :source => token,
              :email => order_params[:email],
            })

            charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
              amount: @amount,
              currency: 'usd',
              customer: customer.id,
              capture: false,
          })
```

No charge is made and no order is saved (as it should if card is bad, etc.)

JSON in stripe

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/missing",
    "message": "Cannot charge a customer that has no active card",
    "param": "card",
    "type": "card_error"
  }
}
```

JS for Elements:

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

var elements = stripe.elements();

var style = {
  base: {
    color: '#32325d',
    lineHeight: '24px',
    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontSize: '16px',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#aab7c4'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};

var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});


card.mount('#card-element');


card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

var form = document.getElementById('payment_form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
  });
});

  function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    var form = document.getElementById('payment_form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    form.submit();
  }
```

FOrm:

```
<%= form_for(@order, url: listing_orders_path([@listing, @listing_video]), remote: true ) do |form| %>


  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :name, "Their Name" %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, class: "form-control", required: true, placeholder: "Steph" %>
  </div>
...

  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>



  <div class="form-row">
      <label for="card-element">
         Credit or debit card
      </label>
    <div id="card-element" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-group">



  <%= form.submit  id:"button-element"  %>

 </div>

<span class="token"></span>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Are you using stripe elements? It should give you a valid token if setup correctly. Check if the customer is created with a card in the dashboard.

Comment: when i use tok_visa it all works perfectly.  I wanted to test with an actual number and didn't work.  The token is valid when i receive it, its coming from Stripe.  The customer is being created, just not the charge working

Comment: @leifcr yes Elements.  I get the token, as you can see in the OP, but when i'm using `:source => token,` instead of `tok_visa`, it won't work for whatever reason and i dont understand. I see a lot of people with the same issue and no1 seems to have solved it.

Comment: @uno Can you try using the token's id for `:source` instead of the token itself?

Comment: tried using token.id, @order.stripe_customer_token --- neither work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding the html post to the form.

it wasn't creating tokens due to this.  Without the token, it can't do anyything

Answer (score 1):

With Stripe's frontend utilities such as checkout or charge, you can create either a token, which is an authorization for a single charge not attached to a customer, or a source, which is a tokenized form of a credit card that can be attached to a customer.

When you create a customer, you create them with a default source attached that all future charges go to automatically. On your frontend you'll need to change `createToken` to `createSource` - everything after that is roughly the same except the variable you are referring to in the response is `source` instead of `token`.

```
  stripe.createSource(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      stripeTokenHandler(result.source);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Dang, unfortunately, this didn't work, why would the tok_vis source work when i use that, but not when entering the card number itself? The token is being created every time too.

Comment: For clarification.  You were referring to the javascript correct? I added the javascript to my OP for u

Comment: Correct, I updated my answer to have the corrected JS in it.

Comment: I added that, still not going through with test numbers.  I don't understand.  How come "tok_visa" works and what eactly is it doing and using test number doesn't generate whatever "tok_visa" generates?

Comment: so im on to sometjhing.  i noticed my token wasn't being logged... i think the way my form is set up is messing with it.... inca se you may see something, i added it to my OP

Comment: Ended up being because my token wasn't being created from the form.  Fixed it by adding the html to the form.  Then my second issue was because i was loading 8 different stripe.js files (due to the 8 variables from the product that have different pricing) so i am currently looking for a solution for that.  Assuming i will need to have some conditional javascript created